# difference between over and for

Tags: prepositions

I have a simple question.

> over centuries / for centuries

what is the difference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For** implies constancy, while **over** implies change. Here are some examples:

> Over centuries the English language has **evolved**.
>
> For decades America has **remained** the world's greatest superpower.

Sometimes both forms are acceptable:

> He has been **constantly learning** new information over/for the last few years.

The fact that he is learning means that there is change (in his amount of knowledge), and therefore **over** should be used. However, the rate of change remains the same, suggesting **for** as the correct word. In this case both are fine.